# FPDF- How to adjust other multicells if one multicell is affected?

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I'm trying to generate a table in fpdf with dynamic content in it. The problem is in the line `$pdf->MultiCell(50,10,$d2['shade'],'LRB',1);`. This cell has a lot of 
content in it. So when the height of this cell is increased, the height of other cells remains the same. How do I adjust it accordingly?

```
   $sql3 = "SELECT  `materialDesc`,`chart`,`materialSize`,`remarks`, GROUP_CONCAT(shade SEPARATOR ',')shade, GROUP_CONCAT(shade SEPARATOR ',')shade SUM(quantity)quantity  FROM `" . $DB->pre . "order_detail` WHERE `orderID`= '$orderID' GROUP BY `materialSize`, `materialDesc`,`chart`,`remarks`  ";
$rows3 = $DB->dbRows($sql3);


 if ($DB->numRows > 0){

   $pdf->SetLineWidth(0);
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
   $newL=90;         ////fixed cell spaced in y-axis for quantity
      foreach ($rows3 as $d2) {

$pdf->SetXY(11,$newL);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,10,$d2['materialDesc'],'LRB',1);
$pdf->SetXY(41,$newL);
$pdf->MultiCell(13,10,$d2['chart'],'LRB',1);
$pdf->SetXY(54,$newL);
$pdf->MultiCell(50,10,$d2['shade'],'LRB',1);  /////line with the problem/////
$pdf->SetXY(104,$newL);
$pdf->MultiCell(13,10,$d2['materialSize'],'LRB',1);
$pdf->SetXY(117,$newL);
$pdf->MultiCell(12,10,$d2['quantity'],'LRB',1);
$pdf->SetXY(129,$newL);
$pdf->MultiCell(15,10,'ROL','LRB',1);
$pdf->SetXY(144,$newL);
$pdf->MultiCell(18,10,'OPEN','LRB',1);
$pdf->SetXY(162,$newL);
$pdf->MultiCell(35,10,$d2['remarks'],'LRB',1);
$newL += 7;  
                                  }     
                             }
               $pdf-> Ln();
```

Comment: you should take a look at the MC_TABLE addon for FPDF, it is made for exactly this purpose, it calculates the lines needed for a cell and changes the height of the entire row. http://openhomeo.org/doc/en/apigen/source-class-PDF_MC_Table.html#16-231

Comment: I'm not getting how to do it man. I don't have much experience with FPDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the NbLines() method in [this script](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php), which allows you to pre-calculated the needed lines of a multicell.

With this information you can use MultiCell throughout but you have to draw the borders your own (as you also can see in the link above).